# Can packages be used forever?

Tags: python, r, package, pypi

Many programming languages have numerous packages available for development purposes in addition to their existing libraries. For example, the R programming language hosts packages on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org), similarly the Python programming language hosts packages on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

My question is simply that I wonder how long these packages will remain available, if they will ever lose functionality or die off and whether they could potentially be stored offline?

Comment: As an addendum to your question - you can create your own PyPI mirror with [`bandersnatch`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bandersnatch), which would allow you to create your own copy of the PyPI central server.

Comment: It depends on the author. It can delete package at any time

Comment: Some R packages have died. I remember a parallel random number generator that disappeared. Something along the lines of no update for *x* years get the package removed from CRAN. MS operates a (roughly daily) CRAN snapshot repository like here: https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-07-31/. But I am not sure of the maintenance plans.

Comment: Thank you for these responses - @burryree I never knew this was a potential :) I will do my best to accomplish this and also wonder at any equivalence concerning R.

Comment: CRAN allows you to mirror the repository via something like `rsync`. More instructions at [CRAN Mirror How-To](https://cran.r-project.org/mirror-howto.html). You can also run `rsync` so that it will copy new files from another CRAN server, but without deleting any files that were removed from the CRAN server.

Comment: Forever is a long time. Even if you use a commercial package there will be functionalities that vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages on PyPi can indeed be used forever, but there is some nuance that you need to understand.

A package maintainer can add new functionality, change existing functionality or even remove the package completely: **the maintainer has total control**.

But because we are talking about Python software packages, once you have downloaded a package version (through a package manager such as pip or manually) you have the source in your possession. Note that the software license that applies to a package can legally limit what you are allowed to do with it, so this does not imply ownership of the code.

It is possible to create a mirror repository of the Python Package Index (PyPi), or you can store the packages (and the particular version) you require on storage you control.

Comment: "once you have downloaded a package version ... you have the source in your possession.". This is true only for a pure python package. Nothing prevents an author from storing a binary-only package at PyPi.